# How do I get information about the Startup Type of a service in c++?

Tags: c++, windows, service

I'm looking for a way to get the Startup type of a service using c++. I am able to get the SERVICE_STATUS data from a ControlService() call, but the data does not include the startup type. I'm aware there is a way to get the Startup Type using windows power shell, maybe I should make a c++ method that makes that power shell call? Is that the best way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to open the service with [`OpenService()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-openservicew) requesting `SERVICE_QUERY_CONFIG` access, and then you can use [`QueryServiceConfig()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-queryserviceconfigw).  `dwStartType` is one of the available fields of the returned [`QUERY_SERVICE_CONFIG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsvc/ns-winsvc-_query_service_configw) structure data.

Comment: That's it! Thank you